# Boot sector says there are zero sectors per fat while creating OBB file through Jobb tool Andorid

Tags: android

I am creating obb file trough JOBB tool like this:

```
jobb -d C:\Android SDK\sdk\tools\root\assets -o com.example.myapp.obb -pn com.example.myapp -pv 1 -k 1234
```

while my assets folder is in root folder which is currently in tools folder of SDK folder. But on running the command following **error** is occurring.

The error is: 
**java.io.IOException: boot sector says there are 0 sectors per FAT**

**Note:** I searched a lot on this but could not find an appropriate answer which can solve my problem. Tried all solutions given on internet. Moreover my C directory have 17 GB space left so there is no issue of space.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to necro this, but I stumbled upon this question when I had the same problem.

This error means that you are telling jobb to build an obb from an empty file or directory. Check the spelling of your source!